# PHP work out difference between two values in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I'm outputting an XML document with PHP from mysql results, in one column I have a bunch of values, but these are accumulative values, i.e.: 1,3,6,8,12,45,etc...but how can I only echo out the difference between values rather than the values themselves in this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $strXML .= "<set name='".date("G:i:s", strtotime($row["tstamp"]))
            .  "' value='".$row['steam']."' color='AFD8F8' />";
}
```

The column in question is "steam", how could I go about doing this?

Comment: What is the result you expect? Give some sample input and the corresponding output.

Comment: What do you mena by "difference between values"?

Comment: 1,3,6,8,12,45, this would be might raw mysql data but i would want 2,3,2,4,33...by the way i can do simple math but its just doing it within the while loop i'm struggling with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to do this?

```
$previous = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $difference = $row['steam'] - $previous;
    $strXML .= "<set name='".date("G:i:s", strtotime($row["tstamp"]))
            .  "' value='".$difference."' color='AFD8F8' />";
    $previous = $row['steam'];
}
```

assuming `$row['steam']` is a single number, not a comma separated list.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dataArray = explode(',',$row['steam']);
$dataCount = count($dataArray);
$newArray = array();
for($i = 1; $i < $dataCount; $i++) {
   $newArray[] = $dataArray[$i] - $dataArray[$i-1];
}
$newData = implode(',',$newArray);
```

Comment: brilliant so, $newData is essentially my $row array?

Comment: $newData is essentially $row['steam'], not the entire $row array... you have other entries in $row such as $row["tstamp"]

Comment: oh ok. so what i would do is: value='".$newData."'